# Is there Windows 8 copy progress bar for Nautilus?

Tags: nautilus, windows-8, transfer, tweak

From very few things I miss from Windows, this is the one I miss most:

[image]

Does anybody know if there is some tool / utility that gives Nautilus features like this (transfer graph & ability to pause copying)?

Comment: Do you really need this in Unity/Ubuntu?

Comment: I believe you'll want to use a different file manager to achieve this. Are you open to that?

Comment: @Anwar It's not like I urgently need it, I just think it's good to have it for certain situations

Comment: [What GUI file managers show most details during file transfer?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1296956/925128)

Comment: @Anwar, of course people need that. not guessing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Option 1: Use Nemo and UltraCopier

You can Ultracopier with Nemo to grab a stop/pause dialog box for your Copy/Move operations. You need to install Nemo file manager and UltraCopier.

1. Install Nemo

   1. Add PPA, update index and install Nemo. Open a terminal and do

      ```
      sudo apt-add-repository ppa:webupd8team/nemo
      sudo apt-get update
      sudo apt-get install nemo
      ```
2. Install UltraCopier

   ```
   sudo apt-get install ultracopier
   ```
3. Install NemoUltraCopier

   - Go to https://github.com/lestcape/Nemo-UltraCopier and follow the instructions on the readme
4. Now if you use instead of Nautilus and use the UltraCopier menu option in right click, You'll a dialog box showing progress with pause/stop.

   Here is a screenshot of the UltraCopier in action

   [image: ultra copier]

**Extra:** If you want to use Nemo as the default file browser instead of Nautilus from this point forward, use these two commands in Terminal

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons false
gsettings set org.nemo.desktop show-desktop-icons true
```

And add Nemo to the Startup application list to autostart upon login.

#### Option 2: Use KDE and Dolphin there

KDE or Kubuntu has those with their Plasma Desktop. You can use Kubuntu instead and see fancy progress bars with pause and stop function. To install kubuntu-desktop on top of Ubuntu, use

```
 sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
```

If you rather want to install just the shell without all kubuntu softwares, you can do

```
 sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop --no-install-recommends
```

Comment: Glad to help :)

Comment: new link: https://github.com/alphaonex86/Nemo-UltraCopier