# What GUI file managers show most details during file transfer?

Tags: filemanager

When transferring many or very large files it is annoying to just wait with very little information. I find it comforting to be able to see what is going on, even if I have to wait. That's why I would like to have something similar to what I see in Windows 10, namely:

1. a **progress bar**
2. **size of file** copied
3. **speed** of transfer
4. estimated **time left**
5. **percentage** of progress
6. a speed variation **graph**

[image]

I know that Dolphin has more details than others, but now I don't use KDE for the moment.

---

*Note about the Windows 10 file manager: I have taken that as a benchmark in order to illustrate what would be the expected parameters. In fact Windows Explorer  **doesn't** show all those parameters in all cases, e.g.  while copying from an Android phone to the computer: it only shows progress and ETA. (I haven't noticed that kind of limitation in Linux.) Also, the size of file(s) copied vs total size (parameter no 2) is more limited in Windows than in Linux.*

Comment: please comment on motives to close this

Comment: [Was there some  Plasma 5.x version that showed a speed variation graph for file-transfer in Dolphin?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/623290/341192).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stable, very complete and very configurable, [Double Commander](https://doublecmd.sourceforge.io/) (meant for advanced use) also has the desired parameters:

[image]

This file manager has many other features with regard to copying, like creating different queues.

```
sudo apt-get install doublecmd-gtk
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install doublecmd-qt
```

One that has the speed graph (but lacks ETA) is [muCommander](https://www.mucommander.com/#download)

[image]

---

### Considering the default file managers:

As said in the other answer, **Dolphin**, the Kde/Plasma default, provides many of those 6 parameters (1 to 4). Oddly, Dolphin seems to lack the "percentage of progress", but [I think that in the past the Plasma notifications even showed a *speed variation graph*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/623290/341192) (6) on Dolphin transfer. (I am not aware of another Linux file manager that ever showed 6.)

It might be a problem having Dolphin in Gnome/GTK (it comes with many  KDE- dependencies. The notifications view will be absent).

**Nemo** seems even more complete than Dolphin in this respect (1 to 5):

[image]

Which makes unnecessary the use of the somewhat outdated [Nemo-Ultracopier](https://github.com/alphaonex86/Nemo-UltraCopier)

[image]

Too bad it is not possible anymore to use [Ultracopier with with Nautilus](https://askubuntu.com/q/33461/925128), which otherwise only shows progress bar (1), speed (3) and ETA (4).

The same is shown in **PCManFM**.

**Thunar** and **Caja** only show progress bar (1) and file size (2).

---

[Polo file manager](https://github.com/teejee2008/polo), although not completely developed in other aspects.

[image]

---

[Sunflower](https://sunflower-fm.org/):

[image]

Comment: I just installed muCommander. It does include the ETA right after the percentage copied.

Answer (score 3):

**Notifications in KDE show all of this information when transferring files with Dolphin.**

[image]

The same notifications also show this information in other contexts, like when you are downloading files from Firefox.

If you install a whole bunch of different file managers on your existing system, you might break things in a way that could be difficult to reverse.

Instead of that, why don't you try out some of the [official flavors](https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) of Ubuntu to determine which flavor has the best features for you?

You can "Try Ubuntu" from bootable installation media without having to affect your installed system.

Comment: could you post a screenshot of that?

Comment: [Here's an image](https://news-cdn.softpedia.com/images/news2/kde-plasma-5-16-desktop-environment-will-bring-completely-revamped-notifications-526007-3.jpg) that comes up with an image search for "KDE download notifications"

Comment: about the image: why don't you capture it with all details (click the dropdown) and post it inside the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116890/discussion-between-cipricus-and-nmath).

Comment: I apologize, but I've attempted to reproduce this in a VM of Kubuntu 20.10 to obtain a screenshot as requested.  This is unfortunately proving nearly impossible to accomplish without either lightning fast reflexes or creating an obscenely large VM image so that I can create a very large file.  The image from your edit is essentially the same as the the notification in Kubuntu 20.10

Answer (score 2):

[spacefm](https://ignorantguru.github.io/spacefm/) opens a status pane to display most of the desired information:

[image]

Clicking that opens a new window with more details:

[image]

`spacefm` is available in the universe repository for all recent Ubuntu versions. Install with

```
sudo apt install spacefm-gtk3    (GTK3-version) or
sudo apt install spacefm         (GTK2-Version)
```